# How «cool confidence» could be understood?

Tags: meaning, expressions

Context:

> We'll help you answer those questions and others with **cool confidence**.

I can guess that 'confidence' is like 'certainty', isn't it?  But it's unclear is 'cool' about calm or cold mind?

Comment: It means "don't sweat it".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this context they are meaning that you will be able to deal with these questions unflustered, and with aplomb.

Cool has multiple meanings. The one that fits best is

> Free from excitement, anxiety, or excessive emotion.

http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/cool

Comment: I would also add that "cool" in this context can mean up-to-date, edgy, and the most modern answer. It is advertising blurb.

Comment: @Cargill - I would argue that that sense of the word does not apply in this context.